# How do I load and save a plist to and from a string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, plist

I know this sounds like an odd question, but I need to keep a copy of my NSUserDefaults in to a database (my aim is provide a database backup / restore feature, using one file, the database).

So I think I've figured out how to load to a file (although I haven't tried this in xcode).

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:
   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"UserDefaults" ofType:@"plist"]]];
```

I've googled how to save NSUserDefaults to a plist and to a string and back, but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the asynchronous [NSPropertyListSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) API or just the synchronous convenience methods on NSDictionary.

Checkout the discussion in the [NSDictionary Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on the writeToFile:automatically method for more info on how it works

Also, [This article](http://cocoacast.com/?q=node/167) has some good info on Serialization in cocoa generally.

Use the following code should get you on your way.

```
//Get the user documents directory
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
//Create a path to save the details
NSString *backedUpUserDefaultsPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NSUserDefaultsBackup.plist"];
//Get the standardUserDefaults as an NSDictionary
NSDictionary *userDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation];

//The easiest thing to do here is just write it to a file
[userDefaults writeToFile:backedUpUserDefaultsPath atomically:YES];

//Alternatively, you could use the Asynchronous version
NSData *userDefaultsAsData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:userDefaults];

//create a property list object
id propertyList = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:userDefaultsAsData
                                                   mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                             format:NULL
                                                   errorDescription:nil];
//Create and open a stream    
NSOutputStream *outputStream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:backedUpUserDefaultsPath append:NO];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
outputStream.delegate = self; //you'll want to close, and potentially dealloc your stream in the delegate callback
[outputStream open];

//write that to the stream!
[NSPropertyListSerialization writePropertyList:propertyList 
                                      toStream:outputStream 
                                        format:NSPropertyListImmutable 
                                       options:NSPropertyListImmutable 
                                         error:nil];
```

When you want to go backwards you can simply do something like:

```
NSDictionary *dictionaryFromDisk = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:backedUpUserDefaultsPath];
```

Or you could use the stream/NSData approach from NSPropertyListSerialization, which is similar to the way you save it.

Comment: What about a NSString to / from ?

Comment: You can write an NSString to a file like this `[@"String to Save" writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]` Or add it as a key to the dictionary and save it as I mentioned in by answer